# Ansible ec2.py not working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ansible

I have problems to make it working the ec2.py script for dynamic inventory.

Installed ansible on CentOS 7:

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum --enablerepo=epel install ansible
```

Configure a simple hosts file and ssl key access. Running ansible:

```
ansible all -m ping
```

Get the expected output. Ansible is working.

Installed aws-cli:

```
wget -q https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip
unzip awscli-bundle.zip
./awscli-bundle/install -i /opt/aws -b /usr/bin/aws
```

Configure credentials file in ~/.aws. Running aws:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
```

Get the expected output. Aws-cli is working.

Installed boto.

```
yum --enablerepo=epel install python2-boto
```

Downloaded ec2.py and ec2.ini from links as in the official documentation (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script). Running it I get the following error:

```
[root@vm09 ansible]# ./ec2.py --list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ec2.py", line 1642, in <module>
    Ec2Inventory()
  File "./ec2.py", line 193, in __init__
    self.do_api_calls_update_cache()
  File "./ec2.py", line 525, in do_api_calls_update_cache
    self.get_instances_by_region(region)
  File "./ec2.py", line 615, in get_instances_by_region
    self.add_instance(instance, region)
  File "./ec2.py", line 934, in add_instance
    if self.group_by_platform:
AttributeError: 'Ec2Inventory' object has no attribute 'group_by_platform'
```

Tried to install ansible from git and with pip, same as boto. Always get the same error.

What I am missing here?

Comment: Do you try `devel` version of ec2.py script? I'd better try with https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.3.1.0-1/contrib/inventory/ec2.py

Comment: I have the exact same issue, and am using the devel version.  Just started debugging, so no answers yet, but just a note to say I'm seeing exactly the same as you (only on Ubuntu, with Python 3.5, Ansible from pip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so if you look at the PR that introduced the `group_by_platform` functionality:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/27848/files

You can see that the code goes through possible attributes for grouping options.  These attributes are made available higher up in the script:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/ec2.py#L435-L462

The `group_by_platform` attribute is (was) missing from the list over which the setattr loop iterates.  Add it, and it will work.

This is actually fixed now (two hours ago):

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/223f94ec563eb0f5fb95465bf440ffddd7828f8b

Pull the latest from git and it should work.

Comment: The updated ec2.py is working in my install. And is working on Ubuntu too. Thank you.